# Data for Moore's Law

Tags: data-request

What is a good source for data relevant to studying [Moore's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law) in computer hardware? I am interested in both the original formulation in terms of transistor count as well as some related metrics such as RAM or clock speed. The Wikipedia article on [transistor count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_count) seems somewhat incomplete and the data that they discuss seems to be spread over multiple sources.

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe look at archive.org's older versions of sites that sell computer hardware to see what was top of the line back then. If you can get a hold of computer hardware catalogs (eg, at a library), that would be another source re the "best" consumer available CPU at the time.